# How to interpolate two values with .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

How-to,

Interpolate the following table in jQuery,

```
<tr data-value='2.000'>
```

I need to get the data-value, that is 2.000 and then interpolate it until 10.0

```
var from = {property: 0};
var to = {property: 100};

jQuery(from).animate(to, {
    duration: 100,
    step: function() {
        console.log( 'Currently @ ' + this.property );
    }
});
```

What I am trying to do is I have a table value that gets updated via xml, and while I wait I want to play an animation increasing the value until the target value is reached or a new value is provided via an aml update.

Comment: That's barely even a valid question. You'll need to provide us a larger code sample and more description than that if you expect any help.

Comment: you can't interpolate anything from just one value, question makes no sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by animating something else (an off-screen 'animated' element) and doing some maths on the `now` value passed to a `step` callback and poking the calculated result into the `data-value` property of the element of interest (the 'pseudoAnimated' element).

A good property to animate is opacity, from 0 to 1, as this gives a real `now` value which is easy to work with.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr id="pseudoAnimated" data-value="2" data-target="10">
    <td>Hello</td>
</tr>
</table>
<div id="animated">Hidden off-screen</div>
```

CSS:

```
#animated {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1000px;
    top: 0px;
    color: red;
}
```

javascript:

```
var $pseudoAnimated = $("#pseudoAnimated");
var $animated = $("#animated").css("opacity", 0);

var animData = {
    start: Number($pseudoAnimated.attr('data-value')),
    end: Number($pseudoAnimated.attr('data-target'))
}
$animated.animate({
    opacity: 1
}, {
    duration: 1500,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function(now, fx) {
        $pseudoAnimated.attr('data-value',  animData.start  + (animData.end-animData.start) * now);
        var data = 'data-value: ' + $pseudoAnimated.attr('data-value');
        $('body').append('<div>' + data + '</div>');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('body').append('<div>Complete</div>');
    }
});
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UJjM6/1/).

In practice, there is no particular merit in poking the calculated value into the pseudoAnimated element's `data-value`, unless some other watcher function was to monitor it. But this would be wasteful of processing power as the `step` callback could do whatever is necessary with the calculated value directly (and/or fire a `complete` callback), making the watcher (and the `data-value` attribute) redundant.